# SSH failing from Cisco to Juniper - SSH2 CLIENT 0: Channel open failed, reason = 1752134516

Tags: cisco, juniper, ssh

Not able to SSH from Cisco IOS 15.2(2)E8 to Juniper 14.1X53-D48.1

**HOST#show debugging**

```
SSH:
  SSH Client debugging is on
```

**HOST#ssh 1.1.1.1**

```
*Feb 11 15:55:47.448: SSH CLIENT0: protocol version id is - SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.9
*Feb 11 15:55:47.448: SSH CLIENT0: protocol version exchange successful
*Feb 11 15:55:47.460: SSH2 CLIENT 0: Using kex_algo = diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
*Feb 11 15:55:47.732: SSH CLIENT0: key exchange successful and encryption on
*Feb 11 15:55:47.744: SSH2 CLIENT 0: using method keyboard-interactive authentication
```

**[Connection to 1.1.1.1 aborted: error status 0]**

HOST#

```
*Feb 11 15:55:51.324: SSH2 CLIENT 0: SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_SUCCESS message received
*Feb 11 15:55:51.324: SSH CLIENT0: user authenticated
*Feb 11 15:55:51.332: SSH2 CLIENT 0:  Channel open failed, reason = 1752134516
*Feb 11 15:55:51.332: SSH CLIENT0: session not opened(code = 1)
*Feb 11 15:55:51.332: SSH CLIENT0: Session disconnected - error 0x00
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve did some research and found that Cisco ssh client doesn’t work properly with OpenSSH 6.9. [Cisco vs 6.9](https://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2015-July/034239.html)

```
Turns out the problem is the new protocol extension for sending host keys to
the client after user authentication (section 2.5 of the PROTOCOLS
document).  Commenting out the notify_hostkeys() call in sshd.c fixes the
issues with Cisco scp.  Maybe a new bug compatibility flag in on order to
add to the "Cisco-1.*" client string that was added in 6.9?
```

And this bug was fixed in OpenSSH 7.0

I believe OpenSSH version 7 was only introduced in the JunOS 17 release as per this KB
[KB24305](https://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB24305)